# uncaught ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to access this function `myFunc()` but for some reason I am unable to access it. I am getting this error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: `myFunc` is not defined. Unable to access the function `myFunc()`, although created in the scope.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            table 
            {
                width: auto;
                font: 17px Calibri;
            }
            table, th, td 
            {
                border: solid 1px #DDD;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 2px 3px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
            <svg onload="myFunc()">

                //$scope.list2 = $scope.list.weather;
                //console.log("line 63:"+$scope.list2);

                }).error(function () 
                {

                });

                console.log("line 68:");
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Kindly, note that I am not trying to perform any action now. For now, I am trying to get thoes `console.log()` functions to execute.

Answer (score 0):

`<svg onload="myFunc()">` tries to call the myFunc function on load. This function is not declared.

the code starts with

```
            //$scope.list2 = $scope.list.weather;
            //console.log("line 63:"+$scope.list2);

            }).error(function () 
            {

            });

            console.log("line 68:");
        }
    });
```

you don't have any controller declared. 
looks like the declaration of the function is missing too. 
your code starts with two lines that are commented out and then you have

```
 }).error(function () 
                {

                });
```

looks like you copy pasted but didn't copy the full code

edit: 
Also you don't have an opening `<script>` tag. You have html, then your code and after your code the closing `</script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `myFunc()` is not defined in your controller:

- Make sure the function you are calling in HTML is present in the **controller** in effect.
- Also make sure your controller (`ng-controller="myController"`) is defined in the module where this template is used.
- This same module should be part of appModule

  ```
    <svg onload="myFunc()">
  ```